# Regex expression the . operator in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am searching for a String in a file that has any non numeric character and no dollar sign in it.
when i use

```
[\\D&&[^$]]+
```

it works but if i use

```
[.&&[^$]]+
```

the code doesn't work.Can anyone explain the reason.

Comment: Can you post an example string that you used?

Comment: . matches any character, not just non-numeric characters

Comment: You can simplify first regexp: `[^\d$]+`, what are you trying to achieve in second?

Answer (score 1):

### Why

The `.` dot in a char class `[]` means exactly a dot, not *any character* as it works outside character classes.

### Solution

What you're looking for is a negated character class:

RegEx: `[^0-9$]` [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT6vX3/1)

Comment: then how should i use the dot operator

Comment: @AdityaSharma outside `[]` it will match any character (eg. `[some chars].`)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the character-class `[]` the `.` char is not a wildcard, but an actual dot. You don't need to intersect the dot with your "not" char, you can simply write `[^$0-9 ]+` (which is however not what you are looking for I guess).